Ridiculously poor performance of my M1Pro in Geekbench score and heavy tasks
I recently purchased a second-hand M1 Pro MBP 14", and when running heavy tasks its performance is ridiculously poor - several cpu-cores are not engaged, for example.
I then ran Geekbench 6, and the multi-core score is only one-fourth of a normal M1 Pro, with single-core performance also significantly below normal values with not all cores working.
The hardware was tested by the Apple Store and no faults were found, and the system was just restored. What could be the issue with my Mac?
I checked that low power mode is off, and I kept the charger connected when running tasks.
https://browser.geekbench.com/v6/cpu/5736206
Here are the test results：

and the CPU usage:



Against which numbers do you compare your results here?

The normal M1Pro single-core score is 2365, and the multi-core score is 10320. My m1pro is a big gap with it.

Is it hot? Is kernel_task running high? Can you return it to the seller?

You don't elaborate on what 'heavy tasks' entails, they could be IO bound as well, the system will only run at the speed of the slowest component. Are they designed to take full advantage of the M1 Pro architecture? Note there's a distinct difference in what the efficiency cores vs performance cores are designed to do. There is now a QoS factor to consider. https://eclecticlight.co/2024/02/19/apple-silicon-1-cores-clusters-and-performance/

The CPU temperature does not exceed 50 degrees Celsius during operation and the fan is not turning. kernal_task is normal. Because the Apple Store didn't detect the hardware issue, I also couldn't return it to the seller.

When exporting the same video, it is slower than my Macbook air M1 , so I think this is abnormal.

@ChenhaoYing What hardware issue are you talking about in your comment? Are you just assuming that there is one?

Yes, I'm not sure about the specific hardware issue, but the system recovery didn't fix the problem, so I'm guessing there's some hardware issue.

As a last resort, I would test how things are in: 1) a new user account; and 2) Safe Boot mode. If the performance is no different, then I would suggest that it is a hardware problem, and I would really try to return it to the seller.
